# Openshift origin builder fails to push to docker registry

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm trying to work through the openshift origin 'Get Started' [tutorial](https://github.com/openshift/origin#getting-started) using the docker image but I'm having problems with the builder; it can't push the image to my docker, it says Authentication is required.

```
I0618 19:34:12.387273       1 sti.go:96] Using provided push secret for pushing openshift/ruby-20-centos7:latest image
I0618 19:34:12.387301       1 sti.go:99] Pushing 172.30.205.86:5000/test/origin-ruby-sample image ...
E0618 19:34:20.595037       1 dockerutil.go:50] push for image 172.30.205.86:5000/test/origin-ruby-sample failed, will retry in 10s ...
E0618 19:34:38.535347       1 dockerutil.go:50] push for image 172.30.205.86:5000/test/origin-ruby-sample failed, will retry in 10s ...
F0618 19:34:59.341670       1 builder.go:70] Build error: Failed to push image: Error pushing to registry: Authentication is required.
```

I'm fairly new to docker/kubernetes/openshift, so I'm not sure if I missed something when I was setting up the docker registry or if there's parameters I was supposed to supply somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I restarted the tutorial after removing all the old folders and it worked. After playing with a number of steps, it looks like my mistake was running the `oadm registry` command after running `oc login` because you need to start the openshift registry as the system:admin user rather than some user with lower privileges.